# Poisson distribution transformation method

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Random independent variables  $x_1, x_2 \sim \ \ \text{poisson(}\lambda )$

$y=x_1+x_2$

$z=x_1-x_2$

The possible density function $f(y,z)=?$ by using Inverse transformation method.

Note that I can solve this question by moment generating function

But it's difficult to apply inverse transformation method.

First of all,

$x_1=(y+z)/2 $  and $ x_2=(y-z)/2$

And $$f(x_1, x_2)= \frac{e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^{(x_1+x_2)}}{x_1! x_2!}$$

$$f(y,z)= \sum_{x_2} \sum_{x_1}f(x_1,x_2)=\sum\sum  \frac{e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^{y}}{\left(\frac{y+z}{2}\right)!
                                \left(\frac{y-z}{ 2}\right)!}$$

In this point I'm stacking. Thank you for helping.

Comment: The sums are superfluous and some restrictions on $(y,z)$ are missing but, indeed, $$f(y,z)=\frac{e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^{y}}{\left(\frac{y+z}{2}\right)!
                                \left(\frac{y-z}{ 2}\right)!}\mathbf 1_{y+z\ \text{even}}\mathbf 1_{y\geqslant |z|}.$$ Equivalently, $$f(z+2x,z)=\frac{e^{-2\lambda}\lambda^{z+2x}}{\left(z+x\right)!
                                x!}\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant\max(0,-z)}.$$

Comment: Surely you realize that the double sum in your comment has no meaning whatsoever (summing on $(y,z)$? on $(x_1,x_2)$?). Please explain.

Comment: Surely you realize that the double sum in the RHS does not depend on $(y,z)$. Why call this sum $f(y,z)$ then? Additionally, why the restriction to $y\geqslant z\geqslant0$? As written in my first comment, the $(y,z)$-domain is $$y+z\ \text{even},\qquad y\geqslant|z|.$$